# Plotting a histogram from lists using pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am struggling wth plotting a histogram with two lists through the pylab module (which I am required to use)

The first list, *totalTime*, is populated with 7 float values calculated within the program.

The second list, *raceTrack*, is populated with 7 string values that represent the name of a race track.

totalTime[0] is the time taken on raceTrack[0], totalTime[3] is the time taken on raceTrack[3], etc...

I sorted out the array and rounded the values to 2 decimal place

```
totalTimes.sort()
myFormattedTotalTimes = ['%.2f' % elem for elem in totalTimes]
```

*myFormattedTotalTimes*' output (when the value entered is 100) is

```
['68.17', '71.43', '71.53', '84.23', '84.55', '87.20', '102.85']
```

I would need to use the values in the list to create a histogram, where x-axis would show the name of the race track and the y-axis would show the time on that particular track. [Ive made quickly an excel histogram to help understand.](http://imgur.com/XVA632x)

[I have attempted but to no avail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyFxG.jpg)

```
for i in range (7):
    pylab.hist([myFormattedTotalTimes[i]],7,[0,120])
pylab.show()
```

Any help would be very appreciated, I am quite lost on this one.

Comment: It seems that's a bar chart but not a histogram?

Answer (score 0):

As @John Doe states, I think you want a bar chart. From the matplotlib [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html), the following does what you want,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

myFormattedTotalTimes = ['68.17', '71.43', '71.53', '84.23', '84.55', '87.20', '102.85']

#Setup track names
raceTrack = ["track " + str(i+1) for i in range(7)]

#Convert to float
racetime = [float(i) for i in myFormattedTotalTimes]

#Plot a bar chart (not a histogram)
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars
ind = np.arange(7)     #Bar indices

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.bar(ind,racetime, width)
ax.set_xticks(ind + width)
ax.set_xticklabels(raceTrack)
plt.show()
```

Which looks like,
[image]